# JAVA> class Process> getOutputStream() not functioning suddenly?

Tags: java

I was working with a project for last 7 months in java , the peace of code was working completely fine ,until last 2 days, (i doubt its 'cause of the update Version 8(build 1.8.0-b132) updated on 14th april 2015 ) .

sample code is

```
import java.io.IOException;
public class Tri {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
        Runtime runtime=Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p=runtime.exec("C:/a.exe");
            byte by[]="1 2".getBytes();
        p.getOutputStream().write(by);
        by=new byte[20];
            p.getInputStream().read(by);
        System.out.println(new String(by));

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

what this code actually do is , runs an exe file "a.exe" which is compiled  of code

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
int a,b;
scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
printf("%d",a+b);
}
```

and a.exe is running fine on command prompt.

a.exe is generated by gcc-4.9-win32_4.9.2-20141023

the java code was running perfectly till last run on 10th April 2015.

Now the process hangs,(because a.exe is waiting for input but its not getting it?)

Comment: Try to flush the output stream.

Comment: Np. Consider answering your question with the code that worked for you. It might help others with a similar problem :-)